# How to set padding of Gatsby Link Component to 0px with styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, padding, gatsby, styled-components

I have made some style changes to the Gatsby Link component using styled-components. However for some reason, when i try to apply a padding of 0px, it still leaves a tiny space (few px) above/below the text (between text and top/bottom border). I used gatsby-default-starter in a codesandbox for the initial build.

HTML/CSS Env (codepen.io):
https://codepen.io/marti2221/pen/mNVJWZ

Gatsby Env (codesandbox):
https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsby-paddinglink-spacing-gedtq

I have tried applying padding via styled-components in a Gatsby environment, as well as a normal html/css environment. When padding is set to 0px on the "a" tag in css/html environment, there is no space around the text, as expected. However when i attempt to add the same padding to the gatsby Link component or even a regular a tag, in a gatsby environment, there is a tiny space between the text and my border. This leads to a larger padding on top/bottom for my BtnLink than expected. I could adjust my padding accordingly, but i would like to know the root cause of this issue.

```
    const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      border-radius: 25px;
      padding: 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: 2px solid green;
    `
    const StyledA = styled.a`
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      border-radius: 25px;
      padding: 0px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: 2px solid green;
    `

    const BtnLink = props => (
      <StyledLink {...props}>{props.children}</StyledLink>
    )

    const IndexPage = () => (
      <Layout>
        <BtnLink to="page-2">Request Quote</BtnLink>
        <StyledA href="page-2">Request Quotes</StyledA>
        <Link to="page-2">Link</Link>
      </Layout>
    )
```

My desired result is a gatsby Link component that can be styled the same as a regular link element (ie. 0px padding). My result is link text with some spacing around it in the Gatsby environment. When tested with regular HTML/CSS, results are as expected (no spacing when padding is set to 0px)

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already made a `styled(Link)` styledComponent, and saved it to the const `StyledLink`.

```
const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid green;
```

However, this won't have any affect on a regular gatsby `Link` component. You still need to render this new `StyledLink` styledComponent *instead of* a gatsby `Link` component if you want to see that styled variation on your page.

```
const IndexPage = () => (
<Layout>
    <BtnLink to="page-2">Request Quote</BtnLink>
    <StyledA href="page-2">Request Quotes</StyledA>
    <StyledLink to="page-2">Link</StyledLink>
</Layout>
)
```